# Age extracted from birth date always off by inconsistent amount

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

I'm using the following code to convert a user-supplied birthdate to its equivalent years from the current date. The output is always off by an inconsistent amount in years and very large numbers in days and months.

```
NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *birthDate = [tempFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@ 01:00:00",self.birthYear.text,self.birthMonth.text,self.birthDay.text]];

NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents* ageComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                                   components:NSYearCalendarUnit
                                   fromDate:birthDate
                                   toDate:now
                                   options:0];
NSInteger years = [ageComponents year];
NSInteger days = [ageComponents day];
NSInteger months = [ageComponents month];
NSLog(@"Years: %ld, Days: %ld, Months: %ld",years,days, months);
```

What gets outputted when I input `"06-16-1986"` is the following

> Years: 28, Days: 9223372036854775807, Months: 9223372036854775807

The year is off by 1 and the months and days are producing extremely large numbers. I get the same issue using various dates. For example, `"12-07-1989"` produces

> Years: 25, Days: 9223372036854775807, Months: 9223372036854775807

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Look _carefully_ at your format string. What is its meaning?

Comment: It means Year-month-day. Could you be more specific in your question? I've provided a lot of details.

Comment: Go through each piece individually and actually read it carefully. What does `yyyy` mean? What does `mm` mean? What does `dd` mean?... What does `mm` mean?

Comment: Is your assumption that I haven't done that already or are you suggesting my format string is the problem for sure?

Comment: Your format string is incorrect. You can't use the same characters to mean two different things.

Comment: YYYY-mm-dd why is that wrong?

Comment: it should be MM (for month)

Comment: I just tried YYYY-MM-DD and no hours minutes or seconds. It doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: yyyy-***mm***-dd hh: ***mm*** :ss Do you see a problem?

Comment: Changing it did not help. Currently I'm using YYYY-MM-DD with not hour format. The problem remains.

Comment: @JoshCaswell why the attitude? Maybe you can just answer the questions constructively like everyone else here instead of talking to me like a child. When people code they make mistakes and sometimes it takes a second pair of eyes to uncover the obvious. Had a feeling you were going to downvote after your first answer.

Comment: No attitude here. I tried to help by getting you to see the typo you made, and then [I was pretty straightforward, I think](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776203/age-extracted-from-birth-date-always-off-by-inconsistent-amount-objective-c#comment34725116_22776203), about what was wrong. Additionally, [please don't assume that you know who downvoted you](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JEjs5.png).

Comment: No. You weren't straightforward at all. Plenty of attitude. Look at the other comments and answers if you need an example of what it means to be straightforward. Go through each of your words piece by piece and see what each one means.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry it came off that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in this line

```
NSDateComponents* ageComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                                   components:NSYearCalendarUnit
                                   fromDate:birthDate
                                   toDate:now
                                   options:0];
```

if you want month & days to be calculated you need to include that in the components like this

```
NSDateComponents* ageComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                                       components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit) 
                                       fromDate:birthDate
                                       toDate:now
                                       options:0];
```

also your format is wrong for month string

```
[tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"];
```

should be corrected as

```
[tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
```

now you will get correct date.

explanation. 
as mentioned on apple documentation these are 1-based. so incase you dont provide a value it will put 1 as default. so earlier your month format was "mm" and it was not correctly setting a month for the birthday hence it was 1986-01-16  so now its 2014-04-01 (in singapore). So you get 28 years which is correct.

Comment: The year is still off by odd amounts though

Comment: Yea it fixed the month and days. Any ideas on the years?

Comment: from apple documentation ...

`Day, week, weekday, month, and year numbers are generally 1-based, but there may be calendar-specific exceptions. Ordinal numbers, where they occur, are 1-based. Some calendars may have to map their basic unit concepts into the year/month/week/day/… nomenclature. The particular values of the unit are defined by each calendar and are not necessarily consistent with values for that unit in another calendar.`

Comment: The values of components that you don't ask for are not necessarily 1/0/anything reliable. They're garbage; they're undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Add `|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit` to your components, change the date format from `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` to `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`:

```
NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *birthDate = [tempFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@ 01:00:00",@"2000", @"04",@"01"]];

NSDate* now = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents* ageComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                                   components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                   fromDate:birthDate
                                   toDate:now
                                   options:0];
NSInteger years = [ageComponents year];
NSInteger days = [ageComponents day];
NSInteger months = [ageComponents month];
NSLog(@"Years: %d, Days: %d, Months: %d",years,days, months);
```

Comment: what is the other problem? I can help.

Comment: The other answerer has already gotten there ahead of you, I'm afraid.